# Jupyter-Themes Not Loading

Tags: pythonanywhere

I am running v3.9 notebook and have installed jupyter-themes without issue/warning. I then ran `jt -t oceans16 -f roboto -fs 12 -cellw 100%` with no error.

However, the notebook doesn't look like it's updating. I have restarted the kernel and tried it on different browsers to make sure it wasn't a cache issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've installed the module in Python 3.9 by using pip3.9 to install it.

Comment: Yes, I've done that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I completely shut down Jupyter Notebooks, cleared my browser cache and reopened Jupyter Notebook and it worked.